# Laravel : Eager loading pivot table and sorting on pivot table field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a Countries table and a pivot table Country_language where all the countries are listed with their translation in the available languages.

The table structure is as follows :

```
Languages
--------------
ID
Locale

Records :
1 - EN
2 - FR

Countries
------------
ID
code

Records: 
1 - BE
2 - US

Country_language
-----------------------
ID
country_id
language_id
name

Records :

1 - 1 - 1 - Belgium

2 - 1 - 2 - Belgique

3 - 2 - 1 - United States

4 - 2 - 3 - Les États-Unis
```

On my countries model I have a relationship with the language pivot table as follows :

```
public function translation()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Language', 'country_language', 'country_id','language_id')->withPivot('name');

}
```

Now I would like to get a list of all the countries for a given language and this should be sorted e.g by name DESC.

I do this with the following code :

```
$countries = Country::with(array('translation' => function($query) {
        $query->where('language_id', '=', 1); // fetch countries in English
        $query->orderBy('name', 'desc'); 
 }))->get();
```

If I print the $countries however I get the following list, which is NOT in the correct order. I expect it to give "United States" first and then "Belgium".

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "BE",
    "translation": 
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "locale": "EN",
        "pivot": 
        {
            "country_id": 1,
            "language_id": 1,
            "name": "Belgium"
        }
    }]
    },
   {
   "id": 2,
   "code": "US",
   "translation": 
   [{
       "id": 2,
       "locale": "EN",
       "pivot": 
       {
           "country_id": 2,
           "language_id": 1,
           "name": "United States"
       }
   }]
   }
]
```

If I check the query that's being run it looks as follows :

```
 select `languages`.*, `country_language`.`country_id` as `pivot_country_id`, `country_language`.`language_id` as `pivot_language_id`, 
`country_language`.`name` as `pivot_name` from `languages` 
inner join `country_language` on `languages`.`id` = `country_language`.`language_id` 
where `country_language`.`country_id` in (?, ?) and `language_id` = ? order by `name` desc
```

Which is correct and if I run this in MySQL I get the list of countries in descending name order.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this perhaps an issue in Laravel?
Thanks for taking your time to answer.

EDIT :
Basically I just want the following query in Eloquent.. Seems simple but apparently very hard (if possible) to accomplish in Eloquent :

```
select country_language.*, languages.* 
from country_language
join countries on countries.id = country_language.country_id
join languages on languages.id = country_language.language_id
where country_language.language_id = 1
order by country_language.name desc
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using eager loading constraints.
This does not affect the outcome of your outer query - it only restricts and orders the  related records. If you would, e.g. retrieve $countries->first()->translation -> then those are ordered by name.

In your case you would receive all countries, even if there is no record in the country_language table. Because your restrictions are only applied to the related records.

If you want only the countries that have a related record in the country_language table you should use whereHas. This could result in something like:

```
$countries = Country::with(array('translation' => function($query) {
    $query->where('language_id', '=', 1); // fetch only country_language records with language_id = 1
  }))->whereHas('translation', function($query) {
     $query->where('language_id', '=', 1); // fetch countries in English
    $query->orderBy('name', 'desc'); 
 ->get();
```

Please check if this will order your results in a correct way. I can imagine that the orderBy has to be chained on the original countries collection, therefore **not** within an inner function.

It should then be something like:

```
$countries = Country::with(array('translation' => function($query) {
    $query->where('language_id', '=', 1); // fetch only country_language records with language_id = 1
  }))->whereHas('translation', function($query) {
     $query->where('language_id', '=', 1); // fetch countries in English
 ->orderBy('name', 'desc');
 ->get();
```

I am not sure if you can order on the `name` column in that case. Maybe it is not accessible , then you probably need to use a join statement.

Comment: Sorry both options don't work. The first one has the same result as before. It's not giving back the results sorted on the pivot 'name' field. The second option won't work because the orderby is out of the scope of the pivot table and so it doesn't know the column 'name'.

Looks like this is not possible in Eloquent and the only option is to resort to Fluent and to make a join.